# Voice conferencing between Pi 4 and laptop

Tags: pi-4, microphone, speakers

I need to do live voice conferencing between a PI 4 and a laptop wirelessly. So far I've gotten a usb mic and aux speaker connected to it and can store the voice locally on the Pi.

Comment: You can use [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC). Maybe this [webRTC example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/) can help you and [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

Comment: Add more information. What is your objective? Which OS? Do you want a continuous connection between RPi and your laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you have a lot of solutions. **WebRTC** is the one that I recommend to you.

Configure the RPi as a WebRTC end-point

**Install Apache and git:**

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install apache2 git -y  
sudo service apache2 start
```

**Download the WebRTC source:**

```
git clone https://github.com/apizee/ApiRTC-examples
```

**Move sources to the apache directory:**

```
mv ApiRTC-examples /var/www/html/
```

**Done.**

Now you should see this page on this URL:

[localhost/ApiRTC-examples/peertopeer_call/index.html](http://localhost/ApiRTC-examples/peertopeer_call/index.html)

[image: ApiRTC]
Note that it's for Raspbian with GUI. If you want to do it on Raspbian Lite, you have to connect to it over a WebSocket connection.